# ffi-napi How to accept a struct containing a char array as the return type?

Tags: c++, node.js, shared-libraries, ffi, node-ffi

I am passing a callback to a function in C++. This callback must accept a struct defined in the C++ code that contains a char array.

I looked at [Call C++ dll with struct containing char array from Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37256751/call-c-dll-with-struct-containing-char-array-from-node-js), which discusses how to pass a struct containing a char array *to* a foreign C++ function. However, I am struggling to accept a struct of the same nature *from* a foreign C++ function.

The struct is defined as:

```
struct Info {
  long ID;
  char chName[128];
};
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
var StructType = require('ref-struct-napi');
var ArrayType = require('ref-array-napi');

var Info = StructType({
    'ID' : 'long',
    'chName' : ArrayType('char', 128) 
});

var ffi = require('ffi-napi');

var lib = ffi.DynamicLibrary('lib.so', ffi.DynamicLibrary.FLAGS.RTLD_LAZY);

var SetCallback = ffi.ForeignFunction(
  lib.get('SetCallback'),
  'void',
  ['pointer']
);

var callback = ffi.Callback('void', [Info], (info) => {
    console.log(`ID: ${info.ID}`);
    console.log(`name: ${JSON.stringify(info.chName)}`);
});

SetCallback(callback);
```

When the callback is triggered, `info.ID` is correct, but `info.chName` is either an array of all 0's (and I know for sure this is not correct), or a seg fault occurs.

I feel I may be misunderstanding how C++ works here and would appreciate any help.